# Mapping Open and Closed Trade in Binance API

Tags: api, algorithmic-trading, binance, binance-api-client

I need some help with Binance API. I building code for analysis trading activity.
My target is know how to map the original order with order to closed original order in Futures market

Example:

- First: I open Long BTCUSDT -> binance generated orderid: 1111
- Now I close current long position -> new order was generate example: orderid = 2222

So now how can i use binance api to get this pair of order?

P/s: I using python to work with binance api

I tried use data from allOrders (https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#all-orders-user_data)
but it doesn't work.